# PHP Notice: Trying to get property of non-object

Tags: javascript, php, rest, http

When I get file content from javascript, decode it and get the value of object. It display trying to get property of non-project. However, the object variable is successfully pass to another php class. May I know why it cause this problem?
I had try all the solution from stackoverflow but it not work and it also display the same error. The following is my code:

```
$chat_info = file_get_contents("php://input");
$chat_request = json_decode($chat_info);
$username = $chat_request->username;
$messageContent = $chat_request->messageContent;
$dateTime = $chat_request->date_time;
$channel = $chat_request->channel;
$event = $chat_request->event;
```

Comment: Can you try print_r($chat_request) and show the output?

Comment: i am also with #Rax Weber

Comment: does object have properties? if so try like this **$chat_request['username']**

Comment: can you please `var_dump($chat_request)` !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also do this:

```
$chat_info = file_get_contents("php://input");
$chat_request = json_decode($chat_info,true);
$username = $chat_request['username'];
$messageContent = $chat_request['messageContent'];
$dateTime = $chat_request['date_time'];
$channel = $chat_request['channel'];
$event = $chat_request['event'];
```

And after it if it show any error like `undefined index`  then the `$chat_info` variable does not contain the value of a key that you want.

Comment: Thanks. Problem Solved

Answer (score 0):

Probably one of the object which you use get from time to time NULL value.
Check this out, i hope that is correct answer.